# Need AppActivate Boolean Check

Tags: excel, vba

I have a script which requires activating an existing instance of Excel. The script worked fine with Windows 7 and Excel 2010.

```
AppActivate ("Microsoft Excel")
ThisWorkbook.Activate
```

Since upgrading to Windows 10 and Excel 2016 that code no longer works and requires a small change to the Window Title to only "Excel".

```
AppActivate ("Excel")
ThisWorkbook.Activate
```

I tried using an if statement hoping AppActivate ("Excel") would return a True or False but that is not working.

Any advice on how to check if the case is one or the other and run the appropriate one depending on which of the two systems the user is running the macro?

Comment: [application.version and application.operatingsystem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.version) might be useful in this case.

Comment: and conditional compilation

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make this work with the help of the link Plutian provided in the comments.

Solution was to use a conditional statement to check the version of Office.

```
If Application.Version = "16.0" Then
   AppActivate ("Excel")
Else
   AppActivate ("Microsoft Excel")
End If
```

Maybe there are more elegant ways, but this worked for me on both versions of Office we deploy.

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub AppActivateAnyExcelVersion()

' No need to update numbers when the next version appears

' Excel must be open

' Rare valid use of On Error Resume Next
'  Bypass expected errors only
'  Address expected bypassed error later if needed
On Error Resume Next

AppActivate ("Excel")
AppActivate ("Microsoft Excel")

' Consider mandatory
' Return to normal error handling immediately
On Error GoTo 0

' No need to address the bypassed error in this case

End Sub
```